# Ruby look behind regex error: invalid pattern in look-behind

Tags: regex, ruby, gsub

The challenge calls to capture all characters including the second "."

EG in  string: FILE_NAME.EXTENSION.OTHEREXTENSIONadasd^^assdassds34

captured characters should be ".OTHEREXTENSIONadasd^^assdassds34"

Therefore I should end up with: "FILE_NAME.EXTENSION"

The regex I have tried either captures all characters after the first "." or throws up error: invalid pattern in look-behind

First example which brings up error:

```
string = "FILE_NAME.EXTENSION.OTHEREXTENSIONadasd^^assdassds34"

string.gsub(/(?<=[.]\S+)[.]\S+/, '')
```

Second example which incorrectly captures '.EXTENSION.OTHEREXTENSIONadasd^^assdassds34':

```
string = "FILE_NAME.EXTENSION.OTHEREXTENSIONadasd^^assdassds34"

string.gsub(/(?<=[.])\S*?[.]\S*/, '')
```

Comment: If you need more details please let me know via a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
s = s.gsub(/\A([^.]*\.[^.]*)\..*/, '\1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SU3T2M/2) and the regex graph:

[image]

**Details**

- `\A` - start of a string
- `([^.]*\.[^.]*)` - Group 1: 0+ non-dots, a dot and 0+ non-dots
- `\.` - a dot
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars.

Comment: That worked a treat! Thanks!

one question is the '\1' basically saying only to return the match in group 1?

Comment: @NateDawg25 `\1` is the backreference to the value stored in Group 1. It is a captured substring in Group 1, not a match, as we usually say "match" in the meaning of an overall match value.